# Angular Input text length always 0

Tags: angular

I am basically trying read the input text length in my controller and if the length is greater than I am executing some code. But for some reason even if Input fields are not empty the length is always 0.

Following is my **component file:**

```ts
export class CuurentPlanComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fullname') fullname: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('city') city: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('line1') line1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('line2') line2: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('country') country: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('state') state: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('postalcode') postalcode: ElementRef;
   .....
    ....

   subscribeToPlan() {
    console.log(this.fullname.nativeElement.textContent.length); ---> Always 0
    if (this.fullname.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0 && this.country.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0 &&
       this.city.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0 && this.line1.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0 &&
       this.line2.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0 && this.postalcode.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0 &&
       this.state.nativeElement.textContent.length > 0) {

        this.stripe.createSource(this.card).then((result) => {
          if(result.error) {
            const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
          }
          else {
            console.log('Your stripe id is ', result.source.id);
            this.sendRequestToServer(result.source.id);
          }
        });
    } else {
       this.errorMessage = 'All Fields Required';
    }

  }
}
```

Following is my **template file:**

```html
<div class="row billing-containers">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input #fullname class="billing-input fullname" id="name" placeholder="Full Name"/>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Address Container--> 
<div class="row billing-containers">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input #line1 class="billing-input" id="line1" placeholder="Address Line 1 (Suite#)"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input #line2 class="billing-input" id="line2" placeholder="Address Line 2 (Street Address)"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

........... You get the idea

I know this is a very small issue but for some reason I am stuck with this for almost 2 hours now. Any help would be much appreciated. I don't want to use forms for other reasons.

Comment: Why are you using textContent? Use value instead. Also you should really use angular reactive forms instead of directly dealing with dom. It provides the required validation for you and many other features.

Comment: This is what angular really isn't about. please take time to read the documentation and learn about **angular bindings**. One of the main things and really basic in angular is using `ngModel` (if not using reactive forms). That is the first thing you should learn about in angular!! Since this is exactly what angular solves, so that you don't need to write code like you are currently writing! please start reading before going on further with angular: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `...nativeElement.textContent` to get the input value, and that's wrong. According to [MDN Web API Reference `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)  will get the text value inside any DOM node. Not the value of an input.

To get the value of an input you should use `...nativeElement.value` instead.

Also, you could use the Angular Reactive Forms, it's better than directly dealing with DOM and manually validating your form.

See https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms